# How to download the application in the app store connect

Tags: ios

How can I upload an app to the app store if I'm not the owner?

I am a beginner ios developer. I'm currently working on a custom application. I'm trying to archive a build and I'm getting an error.
Photo error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTqpC.png)

Comment: Why do you think you *should* be able to upload an app you do not own?

Comment: If you are doing this for a customer which have a developer account, he must authorised you as a user than can update the app.